# Skewness of a non-linear distribution

Tags: distributions, random-variable, skewness, logarithm, cubic

Suppose, it is stated that $X$ is a random variable which has a symmetric distribution.

Now, let us consider $Y$ to be a random variable which has a distribution given by : $Y = g(X)$, where '$g$' is a non-linear function.

By a non-linear function, I mean that it can be either a logarithmic or a cubic function, i.e., one can consider either $Y = log(X)$ or $Y = X^3$.

**If this is so, then what can we say about the skewness of the distribution of Y ? Is it symmetric or positively skewed or negatively skewed ?**

Comment: You cannot say anything in general if your understanding of "nonlinear" is the conventional one (meaning that it cannot be expressed as $Y=\alpha+\beta X$ for constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$): $Y$ could be not skewed or skewed in either direction.  Do you really mean that "nonlinear" is *solely* the logarithm or the third power?

Comment: In the case of taking the logarithm of a positive random variable, see the discussion [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93082/if-x-is-normally-distributed-can-logx-also-be-normally-distributed/93097#93097) (for example - there are other somewhat relevant discussions). For the cube it depends on where the variable "lives"; it might go either one way or the other way, or it might remain symmetric, or it might do something more complicated (become asymmetric without being clearly skew in either direction)

Comment: Yes, @whuber by "non-linear", I mean solely the logarithmic or the cubic function.... More specifically, the **cubic function**...

Comment: @Glen_b you said "For the cube it depends on where the variable "lives"". Could you explain to me as to what you meant by "lives" ?

Comment: It depends on whether the variate is positive, negative, symmetric about zero or something else. For a symmetric case, the location of the center of symmetry is important (if it were asymmetric, the story is more complex and depends on the distribtution shape). If the link I gave for the log is helpful, a similar set of analyses covers the cubic case.