# Examples of orthogonal but correlated random variables and viceversa

Tags: correlation, independence

I am trying to understand the difference between orthogonality and zero correlation. There are many insightful questions/answers on the topic in this forum, but I'm looking for some practical examples. Could you suggest examples where $X$ is a $2\times 1$ random vector (non-trivial), $U$ is a scalar continuou random variable, and:

case 1. $E(XU)= 0$, $cov(X,U)\neq 0$, $E(U)\neq 0$, $E(X)\neq 0$

case 2. $E(XU)\neq 0$, $cov(X,U)= 0$, $E(U)\neq 0$, $E(X)\neq 0$

Comment: It is so easy to find examples of both with Bernoulli variables that I encourage you to look for them yourself.

Comment: And when $U$ is continuous?

Comment: Tiny variations of those examples will work.  Add a tiny bit of *iid* measurement error to $X$ and $U$ to get started.

Comment: I haven't been able to come up with an example. Could you advise?

Comment: Try some $2\times 2$ tables.  Then add *iid* standard Normal values to those variables.

Comment: Re the edit: the conditions on $E(X)$ are superfluous, because the covariance imposes a relationship between $E(XU)$ and $E(X)E(U).$ Thus, if exactly one of $E(XU)$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(X,U)$ is nonzero, then *both* of $E(U)$ and $E(X)$ must be nonzero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To construct examples, use the linearity property of expectation and the fact that [expectations of products of independent random variables are the products of the expectations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/578132/919).**

In many situations we can construct examples of random variables with given properties out of truly simple variables, such as binary or ternary variables.  When examples involving continuous distributions are needed, a slight modification of these examples -- replacing their probability masses by narrow distributions around those values -- often will work.

#### Case 1

Let $(X,U)$ take on the values $(0,1),$ $(1,0),$ and $(0,0)$ with equal probability.  Here is a table of its probability mass function.

$$\begin{array}{l|cc}
\text{}& U=0 & U=1\\ \hline
X=0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\\
X=1 & \frac{1}{3} & 0
\end{array}$$

Because $1 = \Pr(XU=0),$ $E[XU]=0.$  And since $X$ and $U$ are identically distributed Bernoulli$(1/3)$ variables, neither has zero expectation.  The covariance is

$$\operatorname{Cov}(X,U) = E[XU] - E[X]E[U] = -E[X]E[U]\ne 0.$$

*To create an example with a continuous distribution,* let $Z_i$ be independent zero-mean continuous variables (also independent of $(X,U)$) and set $X^\prime = X+Z_1,$ $U^\prime = U + Z_2.$ Compute

$$E[X^\prime] = E[X] + E[Z_1] = E[X] \ne 0;$$
$$E[U^\prime] = E[U] + E[Z_2] = E[U] \ne 0;$$
$$\begin{aligned}
E[X^\prime U^\prime] &= E[XU] + E[Z_1 U] + E[X Z_2] + E[Z_1ZZ_2] \\
&= 0 + E[Z_1]E[U] + E[X]E[Z_2] + E[Z_1]E[Z_2] \\
&= 0+0+0+0 = 0.
\end{aligned}$$

Consequently the covariance is unchanged, so $\operatorname{Cov}(X^\prime, U^\prime) \ne 0.$

#### Case 2

Let $X$ and $U$ be independent with finite nonzero expectations.  You can check that all the requirements hold because $E[XU]=E[X]E[U]\ne 0.$

There exist other examples when $X$ and $U$ are not independent.  For instance, take *any* two variables $(X,Y)$ with zero covariance, independent or not.  Adding constants to $X$ and $U$ will not change the covariance but will change their expectations as well as the expectation of $XU.$  Choose suitable values to make all those expectations nonzero.